# Delete Nested Instances

Tags: clips

Given the following class hierarchy:

```
(defclass ATOM (is-a USER))

(defclass ONE_CHILD (is-a USER)
    (slot next
        (type INSTANCE)))

(defclass MANY_CHILDREN (is-a USER)
    (multislot next
        (type INSTANCE)))
```

I would like to recursively delete the following instance data:

```
(definstances EXAMPLE_DATA
    (instance-a of ATOM)

    (instance-b of ONE_CHILD
        (next (make-instance of ATOM)))

    (instance-c of MANY_CHILDREN
        (next (make-instance of ATOM)
              (make-instance of ATOM)
              (make-instance of ATOM)))

    (instance-d of MANY_CHILDREN)
)
```

If I naively `send` each named instance a `delete` message, then the instances themselves are deleted while the nested instances are not. Though I am sure it is present, I have been unable to find documentation that describes how to perform this operation within the CLIPS 6.3 User Manual or Basic Programming Guide.

The following command sequence predictably results in a non-empty set of instances upon completion. What can I differ in order to perform the recursive deletion?

```
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (instances)
[initial-object] of INITIAL-OBJECT
[instance-a] of ATOM
[instance-b] of ONE_CHILD
[gen29] of ATOM
[instance-c] of MANY_CHILDREN
[gen30] of ATOM
[gen31] of ATOM
[gen32] of ATOM
[instance-d] of MANY_CHILDREN
For a total of 9 instances.
CLIPS> (send [instance-a] delete)
TRUE
CLIPS> (send [instance-b] delete)
TRUE
CLIPS> (send [instance-c] delete)
TRUE
CLIPS> (send [instance-d] delete)
TRUE
CLIPS> (instances)
[initial-object] of INITIAL-OBJECT
[gen29] of ATOM
[gen30] of ATOM
[gen31] of ATOM
[gen32] of ATOM
For a total of 5 instances.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create before handlers for the delete message for each of your classes that have child instances:

```
(defmessage-handler ONE_CHILD delete before ()
   (send ?self:next delete))

(defmessage-handler MANY_CHILDREN delete before ()
   (progn$ (?c ?self:next)
      (send ?c delete)))
```